# jQuery store empty input in a variable

Tags: jquery

How can I store an input with empty value in a variable and than assign a CSS property to that variable with jQuery?

```
    if($('input[type=text]').val() === ''){
        var that = //store here input with empty value
        that.each(function(){
            that.css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
var $empties = $('input:text').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
}).css('border', '1px solid red');
return $empties.length  == 0
```

your code only checks whether the first input element with `type=text` is empty... if the second one is empty it will return true

Comment: I have tried this and it worked perfectly, I think I need to revise the filter function.. Thank you

Comment: osam answer @Arun P Johny

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)`

```
   if($('input[type=text]').val() === ''){
        var that = $(this);
        that.each(function(){
            that.css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```